# How to bundle nativefier app to single exe file and deb file

Tags: electron, native

I made a nativefier app for google calendar. But i wanted the apps to be installed from single executable file like .exe in window and .deb in Linux. how to do that ?

Comment: Did you find a way to make a single exe file using nativefier?

Comment: no still not found :(